# Good practices: When should a non-mutating function ask for a pointer instead of a copy?

Tags: c, pointers, copy, parameter-passing, conventions

Considering a data type which is pretty light, and a function which takes this type as a parameter but *doesn't mutate it* - I'm trying to understand when I would want to pass a pointer to it instead of simply copy. In terms of general C good-practices.

It seems to me copying such a light value wouldn't be significant to performance, and a pointer may cause more confusion than a plain value.

For example, please consider the following code (taken from Bob Nystrom "Crafting Interpreters" book):

```c
typedef struct {
    TokenType type;
    const char* start;
    int length;
    int line;
} Token;
```

In the following piece of code, `identifiersEqual` takes parameters of type `Token*` as opposed to pure `Token`. This might make sense - we don't have to copy `Token`.

On the other hand, `addLocal` takes plain `Token`.

In terms of general C good-practices - I'm trying to understand if there's a particular reason why `identifiersEqual` takes a pointer, but `addLocal` takes a copy. Both functions do not mutate the value, and once again - `Token` doesn't weigh much.

Is there a pattern here I'm missing, or is this just by chance? In what cases should I decide this way or the other?

```c
static bool identifiersEqual(Token* a, Token* b) {
    if (a->length != b->length) return false;
    return memcmp(a->start, b->start, a->length) == 0;
}

static void addLocal(Token name) {
    if (current->localCount == UINT8_COUNT) {
        error("Too many local variables in function.");
        return;
    }

    Local* local = &current->locals[current->localCount++];
    local->name = name;
    local->depth = -1;
}

static void declareVariable() {
    if (current->scopeDepth == 0) return;

    Token* name = &parser.previous;

    for (int i = current->localCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Local* local = &current->locals[i];
        if (local->depth != -1 && local->depth < current->scopeDepth) break;
        if (identifiersEqual(name, &local->name)) {
            error("Variable with this name already declared in this scope.");
        }
    }

    addLocal(*name);
}
```

Comment: Passing pointers is always fast, passing copies might be slow. But this is actually a history question. The earliest versions of C didn't allow pass-by-value for structures. So using pointers was the only option. That has carried forward in legacy code (and legacy programmers), even though pass-by-value is now supported.

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, a `Token` is probably at least 24 bytes long.  While that's not very heavy, neither is it very light.  It may be that the comparator function is supposed to be usable by `qsort()` and similar functions.  In that case, it needs to take pointers to the data because `qsort()` passes pointer (though the pointer arguments should be `const void *` rather than `Token *` — but that's another discussion).

Comment: Another point is that the far-and-away most common convention is to pass pointers. Remember that code is *read* many times; only *written* once. To someone reading the code after the fact, a function that accepts a struct value rather than a pointer would seem discordant, to say the least.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield So the general convention is to pass structs by pointer? I'm kinda looking for a rule of thumb so I won't have to think about this too much anytime I write code (I'm new to C). Thanks!

Comment: @AvivCohn: Yes, in general, unless there is a specific reason not to, you just pass a struct pointer, rather than the struct itself.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I see. However, as opposed to passing, when *returning* a struct (which was created in the called function), wouldn't you say it makes more sense to return by value? Returning a pointer would force us to `malloc` the struct and handle life cycle for it, even if it's small.

Comment: @AvivCohn: The use of `malloc()` and `free()` is not a hardship to be avoided as such. Don't fear the pointer, embrace it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is verging on asking for an opinion, so I should probablyu have avoided saying that I probably wouldn't use these two interfaces in the same program, because I try to avoid APIs where a datatype is sometimes passed by value and other times by reference. But that's just me, so I'll limit the rest of the answer to a reason why you might choose to use an interface which passes a medium-heavy object by value. If you want to hear the original coder's reasons for choosing this style, you should ask him directly.

The first point is that most modern compilers will be able to avoid the copy if they have access to the body of the called function and the called function itself is lightweight enough to inline. These conditions seem to apply in the case of the functions from the referenced code, so there is probably no cost to using call-by-value. [Note 1] So if the API style provides useful information to the code reader, then it could be considered useful.

Now consider the parameter prototypes `X const *` and `X`. In both cases, we know that the argument passed is not going to be modified, so we certainly don't need to make a copy of it.

But there still could be a concern about the *lifetime* of the argument. If the called function takes a pointer and saves that pointer into an object which will outlive the call, then we would need to worry about ownership of the object passed. In effect, we would need to pass ownership of the object to the called function, and we would also need to ensure that the object did not have automatic lifetime. In particular, we could not call the function with a temporary, and we might feel some doubt about calling the function with an object with static lifetime (which could not be `free`d).

On the other hand, a call-by-value clearly does not impose any requirements on the caller. If the called function wants to save the passed object, it is responsible for making the copy and disposing of the copy when it is no longer useful. We can pass it any object we like: a temporary, a static, or a local object which will be reused for a subsequent call.

As it happens, token objects are frequently local objects which are reused in a parsing loop, rather than dynamically-allocated objects which impose a more complicated memory management regime. Most of the time, token objects passed to functions are only consulted, but sometimes they do need to be saved. The function name `addLocal` rather strongly suggests that this function will persist the passed object.

In this particular case, `addLocal` does in fact save the passed object, but it saves a copy. It cannot do otherwise, because it is passed a copy and the copy will not outlive the call. Fortunately, the optimiser will almost certainly inline `addLocal`, thereby avoiding the unnecessary intermediate copy. So the use of call-by-value here has accurately communicated to the code reader that there was absolutely no need to worry about the lifetime of the object passed to `addLocal`.

In the case of `identifiersEqual`, it does not seem likely that the called function will need to persist either of the passed objects, so the guarantee is perhaps less important. But, as mentioned above, I would probably have written `identifiersEqual` as call-by-value, too, for consistency, hoping that the compiler succeeded in avoiding the copy altogether. (That's a leap of faith, and it's possible that my quest for consistency here is a kind of tic.)

---

#### Notes

1. With very lightweight objects and certain compilers, it is possible that call-by-value will produce *better*  compiled code. For example, the standard 64-bit ABI allows structures which fit into eight bytes to be passed in registers, which is particularly convenient if the object is being constructed for the sole purpose of passing it to a function. I remember from the days when I wrote to OS X GUI APIs that small geometry objects were always passed small geometry objects by value, and that there was a note in the programming guide explaining that this was done for efficiency. I don't know if that's still true, but I also don't think this particular struct is lightweight enough for that to apply. Although possibly not common, there are other contexts in which making it clear to certain compilers that an object's address is never taken does allow the compiler to produce better code.

   In the context of this question, it is sufficient to observe that the generated code for call-by-value is (probably) no worse than call-by-reference. If it really mattered to you, you'd have to check the generated code from the compiler you cared about. I haven't done that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So would you say, `identifiersEqual` takes a pointer (the "default convention" for struct passing) since it's just "consulting" the passed structs, while `addLocal` takes the value because it copies the data somewhere, so might as well be explicit about it?

Comment: @aviv: i think that's a fair summary. Parsers are infamous for creating a huge number of short-lived small dynamically allocated objects, and pretty well every parser does some kind of dance to control this overhead. Maybe that's premature optimisation but we've all done it.

Comment: So do you oppose to the approach I described?

Comment: @aviv: I'm very much of the "whatever works best for you" school of thought. The most important thing is to document your interfaces, but it doesn't hurt if the interfaces are also self-documenting. You need to design APIs based on the expected use cases, and you need to comment them well enough that if you return to the code in ten years, you will still be able to maintain it.